# Switch datasource on fly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, driver

Application need to get connected to secondary data source, when connection to primary data source got lost. These data source can be of different type(i.e., any combination of postgre, mySQL, mongoDB).

Application need not to be redeploy. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you want to implement this at the application level? A failover/fallback is best managed from the server.

Comment: could you please elaborate more, how ? Which server have you mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

Confusing question. If you are referring to JDBC connections, your app can have more than one JDBC connection to more than one database at the same time.

Comment: I think he OP means to have a fallback of some kind.

Comment: Yes, we can have but don't you think it will add overhead to application ? And what to do when any of database server stops ?